# Parse.com image gallery open image detail view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

I haven't been programming for very long and I am trying to create a simple image gallery using Parse.com, I have followed this tutorial https://www.parse.com/tutorials/saving-images but using storyboards instead of nibs.

I managed to got most of it working but I'm stuck at the last hurdle, when it comes to opening the selected image full size in a new view. 
Following other answers given around the web I have tried to pass the image to the detail view  in `- (void)prepareForSegue:` but I'm still having no luck.

My code in ViewController.h currently looks like this

```
- (void)buttonTouched:(id)sender {
    PFObject *theObject = (PFObject *)[allImages objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];
    PFFile *theImage = [theObject objectForKey:@"imageFile"];

    NSData *imageData;
    imageData = [theImage getData];
    selectedPhoto = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goGo" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"goGo"]) {
        PhotoDetailViewController *pdvc = [[PhotoDetailViewController alloc] init];
        pdvc.selectedImage = selectedPhoto;
    }
}
```

and in DetailViewController.h

```
- (void)setDetailImage {
    self.photoImageView.image = selectedImage;
}
```

When it comes to loading the image the view opens blank, any help on this would be a massive help. If it makes it easier I can upload the project.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual `prepareForSegue` statements does nothing : you're initializing `selectedImage` to a totally new `PhotoDetailViewController` but not the one which will be presenting.

Try to replace

```
PhotoDetailViewController *pdvc = [[PhotoDetailViewController alloc] init];
```

by

```
PhotoDetailViewController *pdvc = (PhotoDetailViewController *)segue.destinationController;
```

Comment: Thank you! :) It seems so obvious once someone has pointed it out to you, that's learning I guess!